# How to dynamically add a property / field to a domain class in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

For a project I'm currently working on I need to dynamically add properties to a domain class and persist them later in the database. In general, I need a key/value store attached to a "normal" domain class. Sadly I cannot use a NoSQL database (e.g. Redis).

My approach would be to handle the additional properties on a `save()` by identifying them within `afterInsert` or `afterUpdate` and writing them to another table - I would prefer not to use a map property within the domain class but an additional "Field" table (to better support searches).

I tried to add properties using the **metaClass approach**:

```
person.metaClass.middlename = "Biterius"
assert person.middlename == "Biterius"    // OK
```

This works and I can identify the additional properties in the afterInsert/afterUpdate methods but it seems that I cannot change the value thereafter - i.e., the following does not work:

```
person.middlename = "Tiberius"
assert person.middlename == "Tiberius"    // FAIL
```

Then I tried an **Expando approach** by extending the Person class by the Expando class (directly ("Person extends Expando") and via an abstract intermediate class ("Person extends AbstractPerson" and "AbstractPerson extends Expando")).

```
def person = new Person()
assert person in Person          // OK
assert person in AbstractPerson  // OK
assert person in Expando         // OK
```

Both variants did not work - I could assign values to arbitrary "properties" but the values were not stored!

```
person.mynewproperty = "Tiberius"  // no MissingPropertyException is thrown 
println person.mynewproperty       // returns null
```

So how can I add properties to a domain class programmatically during runtime, change them and retrieve them during afterInsert or afterUpdate in order to "manually" store them in a "Fields" table?

Or am I doing something completely wrong? Are there other / simpler ways to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to save metadata or are you actually trying to add a column to a table dynamically? A bit confused

Comment: So the field table would generate one table for each new property? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @chrislovecnm I'm trying to add a column to tables dynamically. For example, adding a "Middlename" to a Person table.

Comment: @JeffBeck Not exactly. If an Object has an additional property it should generate one ROW per property within the Field table. If a Person object has no middlename - and therefore no entry/row in the Field table it would be equivalent to a null.

Comment: @JörgRech does hibernate even allow adding columns dynamically? I would store the data in json and monkey with it that way :(

Answer (score 0):

What about turning your DB into a "NoSQL" one?

In one of my projects, I just used a String-property to store a map as JSON-Object. 
For Groovy it's not a big problem to convert between a map and a JSON-Object. And since you can access a map just like an object with properties, I found this solution very convenient.

Only drawback: you have to plan the size of your String-property in advance...

**Update:** sorry, just read that you want to support searches...

what about

```
class Person {
  ...
  static hasMany = [extProperties:KeyValue]
  ...
  def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
    if (name.startsWith('get')) {
       //an unknown properties's getter is called
    }
    //add same for setter
  }
}


class KeyValue {
  String key
  String value
}
```

I guess such a schema would give you all freedom you need. Even without the `hasMany`, you can make use of `invokeMethod` to handle your external tables...

The getter and setter can save your values in a transient string propertie (`static transients = ['myTransientProperty']`). This property should be available in the `afterInsert` / `afterUpdate´ events.

Comment: Nice variant! I'm using it by setting the properties from within the `invokeMethod` function and persisting it from the `afterInsert`/`afterUpdate` functions. The only inconvinience is that I cannot access them the groovy way by `person.middlename` but have to use getters and setters (`person.getMiddlename()` etc.).

Comment: @JörgRech once you have the getters and setters you can list them as transients and use person.middlename

Comment: Jorg: To access them like that, use propertyMissing instead of invokeMethod/methodMissing.  
  
`def propertyMissing(String name) {
   KeyValue.findByName(name) ?:  throw new MissingPropertyException(name, delegate.class) 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a map of strings on the domain object and store your extra data there manually? Unless you're storing complex data you should be able to cast anything you need to/from a string.

Comment: Yes, this is another alternative to store additional properties. However, It makes it really hard to search within an individual property. I would prefer not to use a map property within the domain class but an additional "Field" table to better support searches.

Comment: Then you might want to create another domain class which acts as a lookup table of key/values for your dynamic fields and store this as a many-to-many association in your domain class. You can use criteria queries to find individual properties.